# Gibt es ein deutsches Äquivalent zu "quid" und "buck"?

Tags: single-word-request, colloquial

Die Ausdrücke "**[quid](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/quid)**" für das britische Pfund und "**[buck](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/buck_1)**" für den amerikanischen Dollar sind weit vebreitet. Gibt es einen entsprechenden Ausdruck, der im Deutschen für Euro verwendet wird?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich habe "Euchen" und "Euronen" gehört.

Comment: Jetzt wo du's sagst. *Euronen* verwende ich mittlerweile so geläufig dass es mir nicht mal mehr auffiel.

Answer (score 3):

Für den Euro selbst als zählbare Einheit kann man meiner Ansicht nach „Ocken“ - eine historische Maßeinheit - nehmen. Der Gebrauch von Ocken nimmt mit der Einführung des Euro drastisch zu, wie uns Google Ngram [verrät](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ocken&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cocken%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Ich persönlich würde "Öcken" sagen, geht aber wohl beides.

Comment: Ocken oder Öcken kenne ich schon von vor der Euro-Einführung als umganggsprachlich für irgendeine Geldeinheit. Ein Ocken war früher eine Mark, im Urlaub ein Schilling oder Drachme und nach der Euro-Einführung halt ein Euro. Die Zunahme in Google Ngram hat gar nichts mit der Euro-Einführung zu tun, sondern damit, dass Nico Ocken um Jahr 2000 angefangen hat viele Bücher zu schreiben.

Comment: Ich nehme an, bei der historischen (Gewichts-) Einheit handelt es sich um die [http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=132137&textview=true] Oka, hier im Brockhaus von 1894.

Comment: Ich kann mich durchaus an "Eier" als solch eine Einheit erinnern - aber eigentlich nur aus DM-Zeiten. (Ansonsten auch nur "Ocken")

Answer (score 3):

Manchmal wird die Farbe der Geldscheine benutzt - zu DM-Zeiten war "ein Blauer" 100 DM, heute also "ein Grüner" = 100€. (Trotz der Doppelnutzung der Farben (alte DM-Scheine) bezog sich das i.a. auf den größten Wert, so daß "ein Brauner" eben 1000 DM und nicht 50 DM war.)

Ist aber nicht so weit verbreitet, kenne ich v.a. von Bankern, die tatsächlich viel mit den Dingern hantieren.

Answer (score 2):

Für den Euro selbst fällt mir leider keines ein, aber generell verwendete Wörter wären:

> Mücken, Kröten, Mäuse

In der Schweiz kennen wir für den CHF ausserdem:

> Stutz/Stütz

---

Danke @Robert für den Kommentar.

Die oben genannten Begriffe *Mücken*, *Kröten*, *Mäuse* oder auch *Scheine* werden generell eher im Kontext verwendet wenn *über* Geld gesprochen wird, nicht wenn solches in einem Kaufverhältnis ausgetauscht wird.

Bsp.:

> Der Müller hat mir gestern 15 Mücken für die 3 Brote abgeluchst.
>
> Der Kaufmann hat so viele Kröten, mich wunderts dass der überhaupt noch was macht.
>
> Rück die Scheinchen raus und dir passiert nichts!

Comment: Mücken, Kröten und Mäuse sind für Geld allgemein, aber buck zumindest ist ein Dollar: "that is 3 bucks" geht, aber "das macht 3 Kröten" finde ich seltsam.

Comment: Zumindest in der Schweiz sagt man ohne weiteres "Das macht 20 Stutz" oder "Dafür habe ich 30 Hämmer bezahlt". Ist nicht in Deutschland auch "Eier" gebräuchlich?

Answer (score 2):

Einfache Antwort: Nein, es gibt kein allgemein anerkanntes Äquivalent für "bucks" oder für "grand" in Deutsch.

> z. B. $10000 == ten grand

Letzteres wird in Filmen manchmal als "Riese" übersetzt, aber nach meiner Erfahrung wird das in der Alltagssprache nicht benutzt.

Comment: Vielleicht hantiert man im Alltag einfach selten mit diesen Beträgen (insb. in Form von Bargeld)?

Answer (score 0):

Vermutlich ist der Euro noch zu neu, um einen weitverbreiteten Spitznamen zu haben.

Als gebräuchliches Wort für zwar nicht die Mark, aber zehn Pfennige biete ich **Groschen** an, dessen Verwendung nicht mehr ganz so stark, aber immer noch erhalten ist. Heute eben für 10 Eurocent.

Ein 5-Mark-Stück hingegen war mancherorts ein **Heiermann**, vermutlich aber stark umgangssprachlich.

Comment: Mag OT sein, fand ich aber dennoch erwähnenswert.

Comment: Groschen und Heiermann sind umgangssprachliche Bezeichnungen für bestimmte Münzen und nicht für eine Währungseinheit, wie es hier gefragt wurde.

Answer (score -1):

Ich hab "Kohle" viel in Nord-West Deutschland gehört.

[Dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Kohle) Übersetzungen für 'Kohle'

- Bucks
- Dough
- Moolah
- Cabbage (also, Geld)

Und mehr.

Comment: Kohle ist familiärer Slang fÜr Geld. Keine Bezeichnung für ein Geldstück oder einen Geldschein.